# Geb Reporter / Extension to retrieve Test Status

Tags: groovy, junit, webdriver, spock, geb

I am attempting to replace some custom java selenium extensions by utilizing [geb](http://www.gebish.org/). I have hit a bit of a brick wall when I attempt to utilize a grid in the cloud (i.e. [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com)). When my tests complete, it'd be nice to send an update back to indicate whether or not the test has failed or succeeded. To utilize this, I need the sessionId from the RemoteWebDriver instance. This can be obtained in a custom [Reporter](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/report/Reporter.html), however I can't determine the success with this interface. Since I am extending the [GebReportingSpec](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/spock/GebReportingSpec.html), I attempted to create my own custom version, which had a custom Junit rule to track success or failure:

```
public class TestSuccess extends TestWatcher {
  boolean success;
  String message;

  @Override
  protected void starting(Description d) {
    message = d.getMethodName();
  }

  @Override
  protected void succeeded(final Description description) {
    System.out.println("Test Success [succeeded] " + description);
    this.success = true;
  }

  @Override
  protected void failed(final Throwable e, final Description description) {
    System.out.println("Test Success [failed] " + description);
    this.success = false;
  }

  public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return message + " success: <" + success + ">.";
  }
}
```

I then added that to my CustomReportingSpec:

```
class CustomReportingSpec extends GebReportingSpec {
  /* I also tried creating this as a RuleChain with:
   * @Rule TestRule chain = RuleChain.outerRule(
             super._gebReportingSpecTestName).around(new TestSuccess());
   * however, this results in a NPE.  Placing the super rule in the around 
   * still results in a NPE.
   */
  @Rule public TestSuccess _gebTestSuccesswatcher = new TestSuccess();

  // I never see this called
  void report() {
    System.out.println("Custom Reporting Spec: " + _gebTestSuccesswatcher + "\t")
    super.report()
  }
}
```

I have also attempted to set this up in a custom reporter:

```
public CustomReporter extends ScreenshotAndPageSourceReporter implements Reporter {
  @Rule
  public TestSuccess _gebTestSuccesswatcher = new TestSuccess();

  @Override
  public void writeReport(Browser browser, String label, File outputDir) {
    System.out.println("Custom Reporter: " + _gebTestSuccesswatcher);
    super.writeReport(browser, label, outputDir)
  }
}
```

However, regardless of whether or not my test fails, the success method on the watcher seems to be called.  Here is my sample test:

```
class OneOff extends CustomReportingSpec {
  def "Check One off"() {
    when:
      go "http://www.google.com"
    then:
      1 == 2
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
Custom Reporter: null success: <false>.
Test Success [succeeded] Check One off(OneOff)
```

As you can see the success method is called upon completion of this failing test. If I modify the test to pass (i.e. 1 == 1), here is my output:

```
Custom Reporter: null success: <false>.
Test Success [succeeded] Check One off(OneOff)
```

Is there any way for me to get this Rule to work properly in the Custom Reporter? Or is there a way to get the browser instance in an extension? I've followed [this guide](http://ldaley.com/post/971946675/annotation-driven-extensions-with-spock) to create a custom annotation and listener, but I can't access the Browser object. I have attempted adding an @Shared onto the declaration of the browser, but it isn't pulling the one in the Geb Configuration.

Comment: If all you need is the session ID, can't you get at it with `browser.driver.sessionId` (from within the spec)?

Comment: While true, I'd like to refrain from having to remember to call a method to update the test at the end of every feature test, and it would be nice to automatically update upon failure -- that's the functionality I really care about.

Comment: You can write a base class, or a Spock extension that registers an interceptor, or an `org.junit.rules.MethodRule`. Each of them is able to access the spec instance, and therefore also the session ID.

Comment: Interesting that the MethodRule works on the extended spec. If you add that as an answer I will accept. I'd be interested in understanding why the second TestWatcher (i.e. TestSuccess) from above didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TestSuccess` class doesn't work correctly due to a known limitation in Spock's `TestRule` support. Due to subtle differences between Spock's and JUnit's test execution model, calling `base.evaluate()` from a `TestRule` will not throw an exception in Spock, even if the test has failed. In many cases this won't make a difference, but for `TestWatcher` it will.

This is the only known limitation in Spock's rule support, and hopefully we'll find a way to overcome it at some point. There is no such semantic mismatch when using `MethodRule`.

If you want to implement your requirement with the help of a JUnit rule (which I think is fine), `MethodRule` is probably the better choice anyway. In contrary to `TestRule`, `MethodRule` provides access to the test instance, which will allow you to grab the session ID with `browser.driver.sessionId`.